# Identify a private IP address

Tags: networking, ip-address

How can I get more info about an IP address, I get from `nmap` in Linux?

```
nmap -sP 192.168.0-255.0-255

Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-10-30 15:06 EET
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.1
Host is up (0.0013s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.103
Host is up (0.00035s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.104
Host is up (0.000088s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.68
Host is up (0.064s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.71
Host is up (0.057s latency).
Nmap done: 65536 IP addresses (5 hosts up) scanned in 145.09 seconds
```

192.168.2.68, 192.168.2.71 are the IP addresses, I haven't identify.

Comment: What information do you need exactly? Have you considered searching in `man nmap`?

Comment: I'd arp em and check out the vendor ID feild of their MAC address, which is helpful for identifying phones/mp3 players, game consoles, and other odd wifi appliances. you can also do OS fingerprinting from within nmap. Note, if you are on a gui system, use zenmap instead and do an intensive scan to enable service enumeration and OS fingerprinting with a couple clicks, plus its easier to read than the log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nmap is a fantastic program, with enormous capabilities. Its author has even written a 300-odd pages book about it. In any case, you can get a glimpse of nmap capabilities (but just a glimpse) by running

```
 sudo nmap -A -T4 ip.address.to.query
```